# Why does the window background remain black in fullscreen?

Tags: macos, swift, cocoa, xcode6, storyboard

I have created a window without title by-

```
 override func windowDidLoad() {
    super.windowDidLoad()
    self.window?.styleMask = NSBorderlessWindowMask 
    self.window?.movableByWindowBackground = true
}
```

I have set canBecomeKeyWindow by-

```
override var canBecomeKeyWindow:Bool
{
    get{
        return true
    }

}
```

I have changed the background color of container view by-

```
  override func drawRect(dirtyRect: NSRect) {
    super.drawRect(dirtyRect)

    var viewcolor = NSColor.whiteColor()
    viewcolor.setFill()
    NSRectFill(dirtyRect)


}
```

And a custom view is added as a subview to this container view and I changed background color of custom view by-

```
 override func drawRect(dirtyRect: NSRect) {
    super.drawRect(dirtyRect)

    NSColor(SRGBRed: 0.8, green: 0.26, blue: 0.33, alpha:1.0).set()
    NSRectFill(self.bounds)
}
```

Now when I do a toggleFullscreen like-

```
 @IBAction func goFullScreen(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.view.window?.toggleFullScreen(sender)


}
```

The whole area of screen is not filled. There is blank(black) background behind the window created. The app should fill the space, there shouldn't be black background in this screenshot[image: Full screen state]

How can I fix this behaviour. Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you don't toggle the window to full-screen, can you resize it as large as you want? My guess is that you have constraints that limit the window's size, or you've set the window's `maxSize` or `contentMaxSize`.

Comment: No. I don't have any max size or min size for window. I will also like to add that if I remove line "self.window?.styleMask = NSBorderlessWindowMask" the toggle works fine. But then window will have title which I don't want.

Comment: Have you tried `NSBorderlessWindowMask | NSResizableWindowMask`?

Comment: Yes!!!. I was pulling my hair from last 2 hours. This works perfectly.

Comment: @KenThomases, you should post your suggestion as an answer, i think. So the OP could accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your window is not resizable. Setting the `styleMask` to `NSBorderlessWindowMask` inadvertently removed `NSResizableWindowMask`.

You should set the `styleMask` to `NSBorderlessWindowMask | NSResizableWindowMask`.

Answer (score 0):

dirtyRect is not always equal to bounds. So, in a window's `drawRect` call `NSRectFill(self.bounds)` instead. Fill operation is not that heavy to affect the overall drawing performance.

Or you may mark the whole window rect as dirty with `setNeedsDisplay` call in resizing handler and be able to work with dirty region only.

If you're aware of possible performance slowdown issue, you may mark window's content as layer-backed and set the layer's color to white - that will be more efficient (this is also the best option if you perform any animation on that view).

There are a few more techniques that apple describes in [Optimizing View Drawing](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaViewsGuide/Optimizing/Optimizing.html) topic you may find helpful.

Comment: Changing to self.bounds doesn't helps. But thanks for the tip.

Comment: Did you set the autolayout constraints to subview to align it when the window resizes?

Comment: Yes constraints in sub view are added. Please see my comment above " I will also like to add that if I remove line "self.window?.styleMask = NSBorderlessWindowMask the toggle works fine. But then window will have title which I don't want.">>Any idea about this?

Comment: could you please provide some sample project? this looks like an AppKit bug to me.

Comment: It is solved. I needed to modify the mask to NSBorderlessWindowMask | NSResizableWindowMask..Only NSBorderlessWindowMask causes this problem.